# PC keeps powering on automatically (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, wake-up, powercfg

I have a nasty issue which prevents me from powering off my computer. I can shutdown my PC but after a second or two it powers up again and starts booting... I've looked into the issue and tried the following:

- Disable automatic wake up devices (multiple were listed here, **non** under lastwake btw)

[image]

- Disable fast boot (is not even listed anymore...)

[image]

- Looked at (cannot rollback driver) the Intel Management Driver

[image]

**It's driving me crazy.**

Even when I hold the power button (when in Windows to do a hard shutdown) it will happily start again after two seconds. The **only** way I was able to have it shut *UP* was to hold the power button right after a proper shutdown. Then after two seconds it starts again but right after that it gets into the hard shutdown process when it's still in bios and it stays silent... (so I'm guessing the startup thingy is a Windows thing). **However this corrupts my bios at the next startup...**

**Does anybody know what's going on here? Thanks!**

Comment: please provide hardware config (what laptop model / desktop motherboard, etc)

Comment: What happens if in the BIOS/UEFI you disable the **S1** and **S3** sleep states?

Comment: @guest: I'm on A GA-X79-UD3 (rev. 1.0) custom built system.

Comment: Try downgrading Intel MEI to v9.5.24.1790 or upgrading it to v11.0.5.1189. Both can be obtained from [here](http://www.win-raid.com/t596f39-Intel-Management-Engine-Drivers-Firmware-amp-System-Tools.html) (if in doubt, check the one marked with "INF for manual installation"). If neither works, I'm out of idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a Shutdown by keeping Shift key pressed till all lights are off, this might really shutdown the machine, I would not expect to see it start again on his own.

Cheers,
S

Comment: This does not answer the question. Hibernation is already disabled.

Comment: And I tried it, but indeed it does not solve it... :(